# How Can I add a label near a control , whether it is in a flowlayoutpanel?

Tags: vb.net

First, I've created a function to obtain dynamically the control that it will be positioned (through another sketch) in the flowlayoutpanel.

```
 Private Function CreateDateTimePicker() As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
    Dim DateTime = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker

    With DateTime
        .Name = ""
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 22)
        .TabIndex = 6
    End With

    Return DateTime
End Function
```

Second I should add a label "Date" near the DataTime , but the flowlayoutpanel dynamically distributes the controls, so the location is automatic. Is there any method to anchor o fix together two control from code ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it is going to be *near* it.  The odds that it ends up where you want it to go are pretty low.  You can use a Panel or UserControl instead, it keeps the label and picker together in fixed positions.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will try to use the user control